# Как грамотно реализовать полиморфизм?

Tags: c#, массивы, полиморфизм

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {


            ReposObject obj1 = new ReposObject();
            Curtain obj2 = new Curtain();
            Curtain obj3 = new Curtain();
            Repository1 repository = new Repository1(2);
            repository.SetObject(0, obj1);
            repository.SetObject(1, obj2);
            repository.SetObject(2, obj3);


        }
    }
    public class ReposObject //класс предок - объект репозитория
    {
        protected int x;
        public ReposObject()
        {

        }
    }
    public class Curtain : ReposObject
    {
        public int y;
        public Curtain() : base()
        {

        }
        public void Work()
        {

        }
    }
    public class Repository1
    {
        private int count;
        private ReposObject[] reposArray;
        public Repository1(int count)
        {
            this.count = count;
            Array.Resize<ReposObject>(ref reposArray, count); //установка нового размера
            reposArray = new ReposObject[count];
        }
        public void SetObject(int i, ReposObject reposObject) //устанавливает объект в указанное место
        {
            if (i >= count)
                i = count - 1;
            if (i < 0)
                i = 0;
            reposArray[i] = reposObject;
        }
        public ReposObject GetObject(int i) //получить объект
        {
            return reposArray[i];
        }
        public void DeleteObject(int i) //удалить объект
        {
            if (i >= count & i < 0)
                return;
            for (int k = i; k < count - 1; k++)
            {
                reposArray[k] = reposArray[k + 1];
            }
            count -= 1;
            Array.Resize<ReposObject>(ref reposArray, count); //установка нового размера

        }
        public int GetCount()
        {
            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что обратиться к repostory.GetObject(2).Work() я не могу. В c++ я бы для этого использовал не массив ReposObject[] reposArray

Comment: Так у вас ReposObject  и не умеет в Work. Должен он уметь или нет?

Comment: Да, должен) Тут только интерфейс поможет? (я понимаю, что эту тему я плохо понимаю XD)

Comment: Нет, еще как бы абстрактный класс

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Если вы хотите хранить разные типы в одной коллекции и при этом вызывать специфические методы, то вам придется использовать приведение типов, например

```
(repository.GetObject(1) as Curtain)?.Work();
```

2) Если коллекция будет содержать объекты одного типа, то вы можете, например, использовать обобщения

```
public class Repository1<T> where T:ReposObject
{
    private int count;
    private T[] reposArray;
    public Repository1(int count)
    {
        this.count = count;
        Array.Resize<T>(ref reposArray, count); //установка нового размера
        reposArray = new T[count];
    }
    public void SetObject(int i, T reposObject) //устанавливает объект в указанное место
    {
        if (i >= count)
            i = count - 1;
        if (i < 0)
            i = 0;
        reposArray[i] = reposObject;
    }
    public T GetObject(int i) //получить объект
    {
        return reposArray[i];
    }
    public void DeleteObject(int i) //удалить объект
    {
        if (i >= count & i < 0)
            return;
        for (int k = i; k < count - 1; k++)
        {
            reposArray[k] = reposArray[k + 1];
        }
        count -= 1;
        Array.Resize<T>(ref reposArray, count); //установка нового размера

    }
    public int GetCount()
    {
        return count;
    }
}
```

И как пользоваться:

```
ReposObject obj1 = new ReposObject();
Curtain obj2 = new Curtain();
Curtain obj3 = new Curtain();
var repository = new Repository1<Curtain>(2); // коллекция только для типа Curtain и его наследников
// repository.SetObject(0, obj1); нельзя, несовместимый тип
repository.SetObject(1, obj2);
repository.SetObject(2, obj3);

repository.GetObject(1).Work();
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @user308210 если мой ответ помог решить вашу проблему, отметье его галочкой